# Move comments to chat failed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, chat, moderator-tools

I moved all comments to chat on [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/24384/25), but while the comments were copied in to chat, the exiting comments were not deleted. I'm not at all sure why this happened. After posting this, I'm going to manually delete them, but I figured I'd post this as a bug report at least.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need to explicitly click the "delete all comments" checkbox in order to delete them. The default is to *copy* them to chat and allow you to delete some or all of them manually.

[image: screenshot]

(screenshot from the mod menu for a random answer with comments on it, on my mod site)

Comment: Gahh, figured it was something obvious like that... Sigh. That's what I get for trying to moderate when recovering from a cold!

Comment: Huh... well, that's not trivial. Expected behavior is to delete by default, since the action is **move**, not *copy*. (Might be worth a feature request to change the wording to "copy comments to chat".)

Comment: @Pearson There are definitely some oddities with this functionality. IIRC, when handling a "too many comments" autoflag from the mod dashboard, there's a "move comments to chat" button with *no* option to delete them from the post - in order to get that option, you need to open the mod menu on the post itself! Also, feel better soon :-)